# Token Based Authentication While Signing up a User - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwt

So I am working on Backend Of A Social Media Web App , basically I was following a tutorial on Authenticating a User Using JWT(JSON Web Tokens) , in that tutorial basically what the instructor did was that he first made the user sign up , and then after the user was signed up and saved in the Database(He was Using MongoDB For the Database Part) , then he returned a JWT Token after the
user signed up . Then , he worked on the Sign in Part and in that as well , after the user signed in , he returned a token again.

My Question is what is the need of returning the token after signing up ? I mean why do we need that in this Situation ? Can anyone please elaborate on this Stuff ?

Comment: If you directly want the user to be directly signed in, that does make sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Jwt is a specially encoded token for authorization(not authentication). So whenever a user sends a request to signIn, the server authenticates the user and sends back an  encoded(with a private key) **JSON Web Token** which contains all the information related to the user.

Now when the user is trying to access any resource from the server, the client sends a request to the server by passing the JWT token.The server then parses the JWT token and checks if the user is authorized to access a specific resource. So you need the JWT token at the client to send further requests to access resources.

For more information, you can refer the documentation:

https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: I am clear with all this Stuff , but the thing which I am curious is about , why do we need the sever to return the token , after signing up , i mean after signing up we are not accessing any protected route as such , for which we need to be authorised

Comment: I may not know about the specifics of the application but yeah, as you said, there is no use of sending a token until and unless you are planning to automatically sign him in right after the SignUp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to return a token at sign up. It looks he wanted let the user sign in right after the user sign up. :)